# Weird GET Requests

Tags: node.js, express

I just using node.js using express framework. Yesterday I saw these on logs. I get that search engines indexing my website which is understandable. My question is are these considered as GET requests in express framework? Most of it returns 404 which make sense but 2 of them received 200.

[image]

Comment: Looks like proxy scanners, to see if your app will proxy HTTP requests. The 200 requests return the same size (758 bytes) as your `/`, so I think they got served with your homepage (not sure why, although it looks like the `?` might be causing your server to pass those requests to the `/` handler).

Comment: yeah, it makes sense. But to be honest I didn't touch anything to redirect to /. It's just how express framework template on webstorm with few lines of socket code.